# Find the next occurence of a noun after verb or a word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to find the next occurrence of a noun after either a word or a verb in a sentence. For example say I have these strings:

```
'reconfigured the scanner and reset the base now working properly',
'reconfigured printer port to the correct port  performed a print test on zebra strips   was able to print a pslip through as normal agagin'
```

Then I want to return

```
'reconfigured the scanner',
'reconfigured printer'
```

I use the nltk library to detect the verb in the sentence but since it 'reconfigured' is not in the nltk word dictionary then I would have to make sure that if the first word in the string is 'reconfigured' then I need to take the substring right after I find the first noun. In the latter above being 'scanner' and 'printer'.

Does anyone know how to do this?

What I have so far is this:

```
if text[0] == 'reconfigured':
    new_sentence.append("It is recommended to reconfigure " + past_tense_to_future_tense(text[1:]))
    return " ".join(new_sentence)
```

Where the function `past_tense_to_future_tense` is

```
def past_tense_to_future_tense(text):
    new_sentence = []
    for word in text:
        new_sentence.append(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'v'))
    return " ".join(new_sentence)
```

Comment: You might try some more recent tools such as SpaCy or Stanza instead of NLTK, since they statistical/neural, they have much better vocabulary coverage and lemmatization.

Comment: you are on the right track with POS tagging to find the verb - have you looked at dependency parsing to then find the object of the verb which is what I think you are after